# How to Launch/Focus electron app from browser link?

Tags: node.js, electron

I need to launch the electron app or focus it ( if already launched ) from a browser link. I have searched and tried many solutions but not getting it to work, so if someone has any experience with it, can you please help?

Here is the code:

```
// Single instance app ==========
const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();
if (!gotTheLock) {
    app.quit();
} else {
    app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
        // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
        if (mainWindow) {
          if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore();
          mainWindow.focus();
        }
  });
}

// Register private URI scheme for the current user when running for the first time
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('x-protocol');
```

When I try to launch using this code, I get the **goTheLock** value as false, but the `second-instance` event is not getting fired, not sure why.

**Version Details:**

**platform**: Windows 10

**electron**: 8.5.3

**electron-builder:** 21.2.0

**Update:**
I added a delay of 5 seconds before quitting the app inside `!gotTheLock`, and in that case, I'm getting the event.

```
const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();
if (!gotTheLock) {
    delay(5000); // 5 seconds delay
    app.quit();
} else {
    app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
        // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
        if (mainWindow) {
          if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore();
          mainWindow.focus();
        }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. If you want to launch the app from a browser link then why you're implementing a second-instance? second-instance will fire if you open an application for a second time.

like this,

```js
const gotTheLock = app.requestSingleInstanceLock();
if (!gotTheLock) {
    if (win) {
        app.quit();
    }
} else {
    app.on('second-instance', (event, commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
        if (win) {
            win.show();
            win.focus();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Let's say we have an application already opened then I want to focus on it, rather than launching a new app.

Comment: you can check for the lock like this.

Comment: It's the same thing that I'm doing if you look at my code. And if I go this way then if the win is not defined (as not opened) it will create a second instance of the APP as my app is launching tray window.

Comment: And I don't know why but I put some delay in the code before quitting the app then it gives time for the second instance event to capture.

Comment: that's not required though.